# Discord.py - How do I make the bot wait for something and will still be able to catch up even though it has restarted?

Tags: python, discord.py

So the title might have been confusing so let me clarify. Currently, I am working on a command that allows moderators to block a user from a channel. (Basically creates channel overrides so they can't see the channel anymore)

The only problem here is that since I use something like `await asyncio.sleep(time)` and I restart my bot, the user won't get their perms back even though the mute period is over. Is there a way to store a timer or something in a separate file like a text document and make it constantly check (tasks) until the time matches up with the document to then remove the channel overrides?

The new solution just has to make the bot "catch up" to where it left off when it comes back online so the user won't have to complain about getting perms back even though his mute period is over.

I also have this incase the moderator wants use extended mute lengths:

```py
time_convert = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}

def convert(time):
    try:
        return int(time[:-1]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
    except:
        return time
```

Any tips or suggestions would greatly help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate and save the time that the person is muted to in a text file.